# Java Ограничения для методов и переменных помеченных static

Tags: java

И какие ограничения `static` будет означать помимо:

1. Невозможности использовать `this`,
2. Того что если переменная помечена как  `static` то она одна на все экземпляры(собственно потому что статическая переменная не привязана ни к какому объекту).

Есть ли еще ограничения при использовании модификатора static которые я не назвал или которые очевидно не вытекают из тех что я назвал?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Вы НЕ можете получить доступ к НЕ статическим членам класса, внутри статического контекста, как вариант, метода или блока.

2) В отличие от локальных переменных, статические поля и методы НЕ потокобезопасны (`Thread-safe`) в Java. На практике это одна из наиболее частых причин возникновения проблем связанных с безопасностью мультипоточного программирования.

3) Статические методы имеют преимущество в применении, т.к. отсутствует необходимость каждый раз создавать новый объект для доступа к таким методам. Статический метод можно вызвать, используя тип класса, в котором эти методы описаны.

4) Другим важным моментом является то, что вы НЕ можете переопределять (`Override`) статические методы.

5) Объявить статическим также можно и класс, за исключением классов верхнего уровня. Такие классы известны как «вложенные статические классы» (`nested static class`). Они бывают полезными для представления улучшенных связей.

6) Модификатор static также может быть объявлен в статичном блоке, более известным как «Статический блок инициализации» (`Static initializer block`), который будет выполнен во время загрузки класса.

7) Полезно знать, что статические методы связываются во время компиляции, в отличие от связывания виртуальных или не статических методов, которые связываются во время исполнения на реальном объекте. Следовательно, статические методы не могут быть переопределены в Java, т.к. полиморфизм во время выполнения не распространяется на них.

8) Статические поля или переменные инициализируются после загрузки класса в память.

9) Cтатические поля не сериализуются.

10) И напоследок, поговорим о `static import`. Данный модификатор имеет много общего со стандартным оператором import, но в отличие от него позволяет импортировать один или все статические члены класса.

[Исходники](http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2014/04/15/10-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-Static-%D0%B2-Java.html)

Comment: а ссылку на [исходную статью](http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2014/04/15/10-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-Static-%D0%B2-Java.html) не надо ? :-) Тоже расписывал с неё :-) но не успел

Comment: конечно надо! ;-)

Comment: Пункт 2 странный. С точки зрения потокобезопасности нестатические поля и методы ничем не отличаются от статических. Непонятно, почему они противопоставляются локальным переменным.

Comment: Как следствие пункта 7, вызов статик метода обходится дешевле